# Regular expression not working Maven fileset

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying use regular expression in `maven-assembly-plugin` which is shown below. 
There are files with the names starts with ABC502. I am trying to copy only the rpms with the 3 or 4 in suffix. Below one is not working.
rpm names are given below

> ABC5023-buildnumber.rpm
>
> ABC5024-buildnumber.rpm
>
> ABC5025-buildnumber.rpm
>
> ABC5026-buildnumber.rpm

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>${project.build.directory}/tar_content/stackcontents/</directory>
    <outputDirectory>scripts/data/rpms/</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>%regex[ABC502(3|4)]-*.rpm</include>
    </includes>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
</fileSet>
```

Comment: Can you show your full assembly descriptor? Apart from that in the descriptor there is no support for regex as far as i know? (Or can you give the link for the reference to that?)...

Comment: @khmarbaise It is indeed possible to use a regex http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html#Using_Regular_Expressions_to_Exclude_Files.

Answer (score 7):

When you use [a regular expression](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html#Using_Regular_Expressions_to_Exclude_Files) to include or exclude files with the `%regex[...]` syntax, all of the expression should be composed of the regular expression. You cannot mix a regular expression part with a normal part when it is used to match files.

Therefore, you need to use

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>${project.build.directory}/tar_content/stackcontents/</directory>
    <outputDirectory>scripts/data/rpms/</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>%regex[ABC502(3|4)-.*?\.rpm]</include>
    </includes>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
</fileSet>
```

This will include all RPM files starting by ABC5023 or ABC5024.