# Maven regular expression to match file is not working

Tags: maven, ant, devops, build-tools, maven-antrun-plugin

I have two files test-200-12-30-2990 and test-project-200-12-30-2990 I am unziping it to corresponding folders. Second task is not working. I want to select the file 'test-200-12-30-2990'
Below is the ant build.xml. I am using maven ant plugin inside pom

```
                        <mkdir dir="/testdir"/>
              <unzip dest="src/main/resources/testdir">
                <fileset dir="src/main/resources">
                    <include name="**/test-project*.zip"/>
                </fileset>
             </unzip>
           </target>
```

```
                        <mkdir dir="/test-projectdir"/>
              <unzip dest="src/main/resources/test-projectdir">
                <fileset dir="src/main/resources">
                    <include name="**/test[1-9].zip"/>
                </fileset>
             </unzip>
           </target>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression not working Maven fileset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417337/regular-expression-not-working-maven-fileset)

Comment: This is ant build.xml

Comment: Was a similar question asked by a colleague of yours? Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315007/ant-pattern-matching-to-select-file-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how inclusion might work in Maven, but maybe we could solve this problem with a simple expression that you already have, something maybe similar to:

```
test-[0-9-]+
```

Then, the include might look like:

```
test-[0-9-]+\.zip
```

---

```
**/test-[0-9-]+\.zip
```

---

If escaping `.` might be unnecessary, then we can just use:

```
**/test-[0-9-]+.zip
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/0vTxci/1/)

#### Reference

- [Include xml files in maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455535/include-xml-files-in-maven-project)

Comment: Its  not working, may be the way inlude works is different. but your regex looks correct