# Ant pattern matching to select file is not working

Tags: regex, build, ant

```
<fileset dir="${server.src}" casesensitive="yes">
  <patternset id="non.test.sources">
    <include name="**/test-[0-9-]+.zip"/>
  </patternset>
</fileset>
```

I am using pattern matching to select only particular file in ant build.xml
But its not selecting any file.
I have a file with name  test-123453.zip

Comment: Can you use `\d+` instead of `[0-9-]+`? Also, the period matches any single character (besides newlines), so you probably want to escape that.

Comment: not helping :(. first of all  ant supports this kind of pattern matching?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, [that regex works fine](https://regexr.com/4emt8)

Comment: your regex is correct i think maven will not support

Answer (score 0):

A `fileset`'s `include` element expects glob patterns, not regex patterns. Nesting it in a `patternset` doesn't change this functionality.

You can use the `filename` selector with the `regex` attribute to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
<fileset dir="${server.src}">
    <filename regex="test-[0-9-]+\.zip" />
</fileset>
```